Nearest letter from an alphabet array for navigation in reactjs
I have one country list array object sorted based on key value where keys are alphabets. I have one section of all alphabets list for navigation. Once user clicks on any alphabets letter content should scroll to that letter. Or if that key is not having value it should scroll to nearest key having value.
Ex: There are some keys like H,I,J,K,Q which doesn't have value in country array.
So once I click on "I" keys it should scroll to nearest keys having value ie: G
How I can check and pick nearest key from an alphabet array which is having value once user selects any keys.

Just add all letters to your content and make them hidden.

Could you provide some example code so we could know how the data is structured?

Example Data
const countryArray = [
  { key: 'A', value: ['Albania', 'Algeria'] },
  { key: 'B', value: ['Belgium', 'Brazil'] },
  { key: 'C', value: [] }, // No value
  // ... other keys
  { key: 'G', value: ['Germany', 'Greece'] },
  { key: 'H', value: [] }, // No value
  // ... more keys
  { key: 'Z', value: ['Zambia', 'Zimbabwe'] }
];

Finding the nearest value
function findNearestKeyWithValue(key) {
  const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  const keyIndex = alphabet.indexOf(key);

  // Check to the left and right for the nearest key with value
  for (let offset = 0; offset < alphabet.length; offset++) {
    const leftIndex = keyIndex - offset;
    const rightIndex = keyIndex + offset;

    if (leftIndex >= 0 && countryArray[leftIndex] && countryArray[leftIndex].value.length > 0) {
      return countryArray[leftIndex].key;
    }

    if (rightIndex < alphabet.length && countryArray[rightIndex] && countryArray[rightIndex].value.length > 0) {
      return countryArray[rightIndex].key;
    }
  }

  // Default to first key if no key with value is found
  return countryArray[0].key;
}

Scrolling
function scrollToCountry(key) {
  const nearestKey = findNearestKeyWithValue(key);
  const element = document.getElementById(nearestKey);

  if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}

Sample HTML
<div id="alphabetNav">
  <span onclick="scrollToCountry('A')">A</span>
  <span onclick="scrollToCountry('B')">B</span>
  <span onclick="scrollToCountry('C')">C</span>
  <!-- ... other alphabet letters -->
  <span onclick="scrollToCountry('Z')">Z</span>
</div>

<div id="countryList">
  <!-- Each key will have a corresponding div with an id -->
  <div id="A">Albania, Algeria</div>
  <div id="B">Belgium, Brazil</div>
  <!-- ... other countries -->
  <div id="G">Germany, Greece</div>
  <div id="Z">Zambia, Zimbabwe</div>
</div>


if no key with value is found, I need the nearest key having value of that selected letter.
Ex: G-> value
H-> no value
I> no value
J-> no value
K-> no value
L-> no value
M-> no value
M-> value
so if user click on J it should pick key as G since this is nearest key with value from J
